# showing a integer number in edit text field in android

Tags: android

I am trying to do the following :

t1 is an edit text
a and b are two integers

```
t1.setText(a+b);
```

but this is not working in android but it works perfectly with javaswing

Comment: I have posted solution try it..

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
t1.setText("" + (a+b));
```

or maybe:

```
t1.setText((a+b).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing like this `t1.setText(a+b);` it search this id (a+b) in resource file like `strings.xml` that is not available. So it will throws a exception `ResourceNotFoundException`..

```
So to set the number in text view you need to convert it into string.
```

In Android you need to do like this:-

```
int sum = a + b;
String sumString = String.valueOf(sum);
t1.setText(sumString);
```

**OR**

```
t1.setText((a+b) + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

please do like the following

```
   EditText et=(EditText)findViewById("ID of your EDITTEXT");
   int c=a+b;
   String s=c.toString();
   et.setText(s);
```

This'll work fine :) If it works vote me :)

Answer (score 0):

> but this is not working in android but it works perfactly with
>   javaswing

It will not, because you're actually calling `setText(int resId)`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Calling this method will search a string in xml resources (E.g. strings.xml). Every id of a string (E.g. `@strings/hello`) will be compared to `resId`, If `resId` matches the string's id that string will be displayed to that widget or else you wil get a `ResourceNotFoundException`

To display the actual integer, convert it first to `String`

`t1.setText(String.valueOf(a+b))`